# offset formula / dynamic range in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, offset

I need to set a dynamic range/offset formula in order to track only the last 5 inputs in to separate fields (for each person). Each month I am adding 1 new row for each person (2 new rows in total), so the range of the last 5 inputs should be updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do this is to use cells H29 and H58 with some OFFSET() logic.

this should work for the "upper" last 5...

```
=OFFSET(H29,-6,0,5,1)
```

and this for the "lower" last 5...

```
=OFFSET(H58,-6,0,5,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to helping out. I tried it out but an error did occur, could you check it out. https://i.imgur.com/NaFzfLu.png

Comment: change my commas to semicolons